# How to make an entry box on Tkinter global

Tags: python, tkinter, input

I have created an Entry() box in the main body of the code and want to use the data inputted in a function. I have tried to use parameters but they are not working.

I want to use the data in the validation function.

This is the entry box in the main body of the code:

```
username_input_box = Entry(root, width=30)
username_input_box.place(x=200, y=153)  # name enter box
username_input_box.get()

password_input_box = Entry(root, width=30)
password_input_box.place(x=200, y=180)  # password enter box
password_input_box.get()
```

I Then call the function from another function:

```
    login_button = Button(root, text="Click here to enter data", command=validation(username_input_box.get(), password_input_box.get()))
```

And try use the parameters:

```
def validation(username1, password1):
```

It says parameter 'username1' value is not used. any ideas?

thanks xx

Comment: Is this the complete code? If so pls show us how u put them together. "parameter  'username1 value is not used'" might be a warning which you may ignore if you are not using that variable

Answer (score 1):

It might happen because the `command` attribute of the button takes a function as the parameter which executes when you click on the button, but you are actually executing the function there itself. The way you call functions with parameters, is by using lambdas.

you can simply do -

```
def validation(username, password):
    print(username, password)

login_button = Button(root, text = "Click here to enter data", 
command = lambda : validation(username_input_box.get(), password_input_box.get()))
login_button.place() #Place the button
```